# Removing White Space between Shiny Dashboard Header and Leaflet Map

Tags: r, leaflet, shinydashboard

I have a Shiny app that displays a leaflet map.  I am trying to remove white space between the Shiny dashboard header and the map.  I also want to remove white space on the side margins.  I suspect that doing this requires modifying margins or padding through CSS but I have not found the solution.

Here's the code for a simplified version of my app -

````
```{r}
ui <- navbarPage("Example Page", id = "nav",
       tabPanel("Some Header",
                tags$style(type = "text/css", "#map {height: 
                calc(100vh - 70px) !important;}"), 
                  leafletOutput("map")))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
             output$map <- renderLeaflet({
            leaflet() %>%
            addTiles() %>% 
            setView(lng = -93.85, lat = 37.45, zoom = 5)})
}

shinyApp(ui, server)

```
````

Here's an image of the resulting app.  I want to know how I can modify this code to remove all whitespace.

Example_App

[image]

Comment: I'd view the app in, say, Chrome and then right click over the gap in question and click 'Inspect'. From here, you'll be able to adjust the margin size of the elements in question. If that works then you could adjust the css of the element in question by adding the css to the app. (See the Shiny help page on rstudio.com for further details.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

p0bs, your comment put me on the right track.  Here's the code I used to reformat this Shiny app so that there's no whitespace -

````
```{r}
ui <- navbarPage("Example Page", id = "nav",
       tabPanel("Some Header",
                tags$style(type = "text/css", "#map {height: calc(100vh - 
53px) !important;}"), 
                  leafletOutput("map")),
         tags$style(type = "text/css", ".container-fluid {padding-left:0px;
                    padding-right:0px;}"),
         tags$style(type = "text/css", ".navbar {margin-bottom: .5px;}"),
        tags$style(type = "text/css", ".container-fluid .navbar-header 
.navbar-brand {margin-left: 0px;}"))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
output$map <- renderLeaflet({
leaflet() %>%
  addTiles() %>% 
  setView(lng = -93.85, lat = 37.45, zoom = 5)})
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```
````

Here's an image of the result -

[image]